# how to capture log messages from dependency project java or vice versa

Tags: java, maven, logging, pom.xml

I am looking for help with my below mentioned scenario.

I have a "main" java project and a externally pom loaded java project.

"main" project - I have a java project enabled with both console and file logging and works super file, logging all events to log file.

"external or lib" project - Another similar project enabled with logging

Question is - (This is where I need help) - When "external or lib" project is included in "main" project's pom as dependencies and some of the classes-methods from "lib" project are being called, I am unable to collect their messages. As in, I am unable to see the called methods logged (debug/error) messages...